# Amazon SNS Policy to restrict subscriptions is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am creating one SNS topic in account A with below policy:

```
{
     "Sid": "Give Access to Different Account Queues to subscribe to my topic",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal":{
       "AWS": "AccountId of Account B"
     },
     "Action": "sns:Subscribe",
     "Resource": "Arn of my SNS topic present in Account A",
     "Condition": {
       "StringEquals": {
          "sns:Protocol": "sqs"
       },
       "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "sns:Endpoint": [
             "Arn of Queue A present in Account B", "Arn Queue B present in Account B"
          ]
       }
     }
  }
```

After creating the above topic and policy in Account A. Then, I am logging into Account B through console and trying to subscribe Queue C to my SNS topic then also subscription is successful and queue is getting message for confirming subscription! But ideally after above policy only Queue A and Queue B should be able to subscribe to My SNS topic.

Comment: I wonder if it is because the user who requested the subscription has additional `sns:` policies associated with their IAM User? You could try again, using an IAM User that has no `sns:` permissions. How is the subscription being requested?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using subscriptionFilter resource in Cloud Formation to subscribe to my SNS. Also the account is the Root Account

Comment: If the SNS topic is in Account-A, are you saying that any queue in Account-A can subscribe, or any queue in the other account (Account-B) can subscribe?

Comment: If the topic is in account A and we have two queues in account B! Then only those two queue can subscribe to my Topic A.

Comment: But in your question you say _"any queue is able to subscribe to my SNS topic from **that account**"_. I am asking _which_ account that is? The one with SNS, or the 'other' account?

Comment: The other account!
And the one with sns also because I didn't put any restrictions for that!

Comment: Please edit your question to provide full details of how the SQS queue is subscribing to the topic (eg using console? AWS CLI?) and how you have tested the configuration that leads you to the stated findings. This way, we can attempt to reproduce your configuration and determine why it is behaving this way.

Comment: Thankyou! Edited the question. Please let me know if something more is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your policy worked perfectly fine for me, but I had to change the `Principal` to reference `arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-B:root`. (I can't remember where I got that from, but it appeared at some stage.)

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-B:root"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:ACCOUNT-A:topic",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sns:Protocol": "sqs"
        },
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "sns:Endpoint": [
            "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:ACCOUNT-B:queue1",
            "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:ACCOUNT-B:queue2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I was able to subscribe from `queue1` and `queue2`, but not `queue3`.

Comment: Yes when we assign accountId to Principal it automatically changes to root account arn! Also, I think Account B in my case have some other permissions. Can we deny every sqs in Account A to subscribe?

Comment: It worked after explicitly denying other sqs arn's with StringNotEquals! Thankyou